# How to track a face using android/IOS devices in Unity?

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, tracking, arkit

Recently with the release of ARkit 2.0 face tracking was possible in IOS devices.I tried the example eyes and tongue on my Ipad pro but it did not work.It only works in IPHONE X I believe.Is there any way we could do it using Unity engine so that the app will be working in older phones as well.

Comment: It’s possible to do in Unity. If you take a look the OpenCV asset they have an example. This being said it isn’t cheap but if you have no other option then it’s a good investment and depending on your competency with OpenCV a solid investment :)

Comment: @BlackMirrorz...this one ?? https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088

Comment: Yeah and if I recall you may need the Dlib face detector which goes with it. Can’t recall if that’s free or not :)

Comment: Dlib has a really excellent facial tracker, though it is computationally expensive and may not work on older phones. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/dlib-facelandmark-detector-64314